# Azure login - new mobile number

Tags: azure, authentication

I've moved recently from country A to B. Unfortunately I cannot login anymore to my Azure account. I have a personal account not an organizational account.
I've followed all steps here [Common problems with two-step verification for a work or school account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/common-problems-with-two-step-verification-for-a-work-or-school-account-63acbb9b-16a1-47b9-8619-6a865e8071a5) but still did not succeed. I've logged in to my outlook account and added a new QR code for the authenticator app, but this works only for my outlook account.

I always get the screen which only shows my old mobile number[image]

I cannot open an Azure support ticket as I cannot login anymore.

How can I add my new mobile number so that I can get a code to login to Azure in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the only way is to contact support via
https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/overview/contact-azure-sales/#phone-numbers